# Mistral does not finish the answers

Tags: openai-api, large-language-model, mistral-7b

I am developing a web application to be able to answer questions based on the context provided by documents that the user uploads to the application.
The problem is that when I use the Mistral v0.2 model, the answers do not finish. They are cut off before finishing. If I use openai, the answers finish correctly.
I use this prompt:

```
template="""
    ### [INST] Instruccion: Responde en español a las preguntas del usuario según el contexto.
    Si no encunetras una respuesta adecuada en el contexto, responde que no tienes información suficiente.

    {context}

    ### question:
    {question} (responde en castellano) [/INST]
    #"""
    template="""
    <s>[INST]
    """
prompt = PromptTemplate(
        input_variables=['context','question'],
        template = template
    )
vector = Chroma(client=db,
        collection_name="coleccion4",
        embedding_function=embeddings)
retriever = vector.as_retriever(search_type="similarity", search_kwargs={"k":3})
llm = HuggingFaceHub(
        repo_id="mistralai/Mistral-7B-Instruct-v0.2",
        model_kwargs = {"temperature":0.4},
        huggingfacehub_api_token = apikey_huggingFace
    )
respuesta = rag_chain.invoke(user_question)
```

when I run the code with openai, I get this response:
[image]

But when I use Mistral, the answer does not end:
[image]

why does this happen?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have set max_new_tokens to 2000 and now it seems to work

Comment: I don't think increasing the max token works all the time. There could be cases where the output tokens are less than max but the answer is still partial/incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues that could be going on here -

1. Ram Limit Reached: Please make sure you have more that 8.0 ram usable
2. Temparature - 0.4 is very specific and may cause short responses
3. Token Limit - Try specifying a token limit to the desired lenght of your
   response.